# Chicken on a Brinkmann Smoker N Grill

Tags: chicken, barbecue, smoking

I've been trying to smoke chicken for many days now, but the problem is that most of the time the chicken tastes like a match.

I've done everything, soaked the wood for a long time, cooked it with indirect heat with a pan of water in the middle. I have tried both wood chips and big pieces (soaked and dry) and, of course, all that with charcoal. Can anyone please advise me?

Comment: Welcome ChickenBBQ! Did you follow the instructions that came with your smoker/bbq or another set of instructions?  Can you share a bit more information on the chicken results? Was it whole or pieces?  Was it burnt or dry?  How long did you smoke it? What was the temperature of the smoker?  Did you bbq it too?  All or any of this info will help us help you. :-)

Comment: Yes sure, it was a whole chicken, it was really tender and perfectly cooked, and by the way the skin was really not good, it was kinda rubbery. I just smoked it, didn't bbq it. the thermometer has no degrees in it, there are 3 words (Warm, Ideal and Hot) and it was almost always in the middle of Ideal.

Comment: Please don't select a correct answer too quickly, other people may have better answer, but may not answer it now

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've may have two issues. Too much wood and incorrect expectations.

First it sounds like you've "oversmoked" your chicken. Depending on what kind of wood you use too won't need much for chicken (remember it's a lightly flavored meat.) try less wood next time.

Second that "ideal"temperature is great off you want pulled chicken but it will not do god things to the skin. Try either smoking at a higher temp for a shorter time, discarding the skin or finishing it on a grill.

Lastly if your meat had a bitter flavor it could be that you had live flames rather than embers as you smoked. Remember that you want to avoid flareups as much as possible.